# django_ct filter for django haystack not returning results

Tags: django, django-haystack

I've upgraded haystack but I'm getting an issue with using `django_ct` I've indexed the model for movie with `python manage.py update_index movies` but when I try to get a filter by model using either of the two

```
result = SearchQuerySet().raw_search('django_ct:movies.movie')
result = SearchQuerySet().filter(django_ct='movies.movie')
```

I get no result

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> result = SearchQuerySet().filter(django_ct='movies.movie')
>>> len(result.all())
0
>>> len(result)
0
>>> result = SearchQuerySet().raw_search('django_ct:movies.movie')
>>> len(result)
0
>>> len(result.all())
0
>>> all_result = SearchQuerySet()
>>> len(all_result)
10924
>>>
```

The index for Movies is

```
import datetime

from django.db.models import Q

from haystack import indexes

from search.base_search_index import BaseSearchIndex
from search.fields import MultiValueDateField
from movies.models import Movie, Show


class MovieIndex(BaseSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    dates = MultiValueDateField(null=True,)
    areas = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)
    categories = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)
    venues = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)
    hot = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='is_hot')
    showing = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='now_showing')

    sortorder = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='sortorder')
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')

    def prepare_areas(self, obj):
        shows = obj.shows.all()
        areas = []
        if shows:
            for s in shows:
                if s.venue and s.venue.area_id:
                    areas.append(s.venue.area_id)
        return self.get_list_for_multivalue_field(areas)

    def prepare_venues(self, obj):
        shows = obj.shows.all()
        if shows:
            return [show.venue_id for show in shows]
        return None

    def prepare_categories(self, obj):
        cats = []
        for category in obj.categories.all():
            cats.extend([c.id for c in category.get_ancestors(include_self=True)])
        return self.get_list_for_multivalue_field(cats)

    def prepare_dates(self, obj):
        dates = [d for d in obj.start_dates()]
        return dates

    def get_model(self):
        return Movie

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(
            Q(visible=True) &
            Q(publish__lte=datetime.date.today()) &
            (Q(expires__isnull=True) | Q(expires__gte=datetime.date.today())) &
            Q(shows__starts__gte=datetime.date.today()),

        ).distinct()

class ShowIndex(BaseSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    movie = indexes.IntegerField(null=True)
    venue = indexes.IntegerField(null=True)
    starts = indexes.DateField(model_attr='starts')
    area = indexes.IntegerField(null=True,)
    categories = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)
    hot = indexes.BooleanField()
    i = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='movie__pk')
    shows = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='pk')

    def prepare_movie(self, obj):
        if obj.movie_id:
            return obj.movie_id
        return -1

    def prepare_venue(self, obj):
        if obj.venue_id:
            return obj.venue_id
        return -1

    def prepare_area(self, obj):
        if obj.venue.area_id:
            return obj.venue.area_id
        return -1

    def prepare_categories(self, obj):
        cats = []
        for category in obj.movie.categories.all():
            cats.extend([c.id for c in category.get_ancestors(include_self=True)])
        return self.get_list_for_multivalue_field(cats)

    def prepare_hot(self, obj):
        return obj.movie.is_hot()

    def prepare_slug(self, obj):
        return u''

    def prepare(self, obj):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        data = super(BaseSearchIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        data['boost'] = 1
        return data

    def get_model(self):
        return Show

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(starts__gte=datetime.date.today()).distinct()
```

and it's inheritance

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q
from haystack import indexes


class BaseSearchIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    html = indexes.CharField(use_template=True, indexed=False)
    json = indexes.CharField(use_template=True, indexed=False)
    slug = indexes.CharField()
    #pk_xapian = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='pk')
    i = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='pk')

    def prepare_slug(self, obj):
        return u'unique%sunique' % obj.slug

    def get_updated_field(self):
        return 'modified'

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(
            Q(visible=True) &
            Q(publish__lte=today) &
            (Q(expires__isnull=True) | Q(expires__gte=today))
        ).distinct()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        data = super(BaseSearchIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        weeks = (today - obj.created).days / 7 + 1
        data['boost'] = 1 + (1.0 / weeks)
        return data

    def get_list_for_multivalue_field(self, value):
        if len(value) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(value) == 1:
            return [value[0],]
        return value
```

The search works but the logic used to get the data to json for an app has  the logic with searchqueryset and filters per model and returns nothing.

Comment: I had this problem as xapian indexer. I was able to correct the problem [https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack/issues/165](#165)